# Difference between parameters and members of a class

Tags: record, coq, typeclass, dependent-type

I am new to Coq and was wondering what is the difference between the following things:

```
Class test (f g: nat -> nat) := {
  init:   f 0 = 0 /\ g 0 = 0;
  output: ...another proposition about f and g...;
}.
```

and

```
Class test := {
  f: nat -> nat;
  g: nat -> nat;
  init:   f 0 = 0 /\ g 0 = 0;
  output: ...another proposition about f and g...;
}.
```

Could anyone provide an explanation ?

Comment: For those interested in Proof Assistants, there is a new proposed SE site [ProofAssistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=NjQzMjU3YTVjNzdhOWMzMGI1ZDMxN2ExMmVjZjNlMDI0Y2U0OGQyY2YxOGUxNjE4YmUxMWE3MGVlNjEwZmZhYvQzSfPUP9ckbNrxkouh5gaYRPNF7ix3vwBaRKqqkc730)

Answer (score 6):

The difference between them is referred to as bundling.

```
Class test (f g: nat -> nat) := {
  init:   f 0 = 0 /\ g 0 = 0;
  output: ...another proposition about f and g...;
}.
```

is unbundled, and

```
Class test := {
  f: nat -> nat;
  g: nat -> nat;
  init:   f 0 = 0 /\ g 0 = 0;
  output: ...another proposition about f and g...;
}.
```

is bundled.

The advantage of bundling is that you don't need to always provide `f` and `g`. The advantage of unbundling is that you can have different instances of the same class sharing the same `f` and `g`. If you bundle them, Coq will not be easily convinced that different instances share parameters.

You can read more about this in [Type Classes for Mathematics in Type Theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/48202776_Type_Classes_for_Mathematics_in_Type_Theory).

Answer (score 5):

To complement Ana’s excellent answer, here is a practical difference:

- the unbundled version (call it `utest`) allows you to write the logical statement `utest f g` about a specific pair of functions `f` and `g`,
- whereas the bundled version (call it `btest`) allows you to state that there exists a pair of functions which satisfies the properties; you can later refer to these functions by the projection names `f` and `g`.

So, roughly speaking:

- `btest` is “equivalent” to `∃ f g, utest f g`;
- `utest f' g'` is “equivalent” to `btest  ∧  “the f (resp. g) in the aforementioned proof of btest is equal to f' (resp. g')”`.

More formally, here are the equivalences for a minimal example
(in this code, the notation `{ x : A | B }` is a **dependent pair** type,
i.e. the type of `(x, y)` where `x : A` and `y : B`
and the type `B` depends on the value `x`):

```
(* unbundled: *)
Class utest (x : nat) : Prop := {
  uprop : x = 0;
}.

(* bundled: *)
Class btest : Type := {
  bx : nat;
  bprop : bx = 0;
}.

(* [btest] is equivalent to: *)

Goal { x : nat | utest x } -> btest.
Proof.
  intros [x u]. econstructor. exact (@uprop x u).
Qed.

Goal btest -> { x : nat | utest x }.
Proof.
  intros b. exists (@bx b). constructor. exact (@bprop b).
Qed.

(* [utest x] is equivalent to: *)

Goal forall x, { b : btest | @bx b = x } -> utest x.
Proof.
  intros x [b <-]. constructor. exact (@bprop b).
Qed.

Goal forall x, utest x -> { b : btest | @bx b = x }.
Proof.
  intros x u. exists {| bx := x ; bprop := @uprop x u |}. reflexivity.
Qed.

(* NOTE: Here I’ve explicited all implicit arguments; in fact, you
   can let Coq infer them, and write just [bx], [bprop], [uprop]
   instead of [@bx b], [@bprop b], [@uprop x u]. *)
```

In this example, we can also observe a difference with respect to computational relevance: `utest` can live in `Prop`, because its only member, `uprop`, is a proposition. On the other hand, I cannot really put `btest` in `Prop`, because that would mean that *both* `bx` and `bprop` would live in `Prop` but `bf` is computationally relevant. In other words, Coq gives you this warning:

```
Class btest : Prop := {
  bx : nat;
  bprop : bx = 0;
}.
(* WARNING:
     bx cannot be defined because it is informative and btest is not.
     bprop cannot be defined because the projection bx was not defined.
*)
```